# vcluster development install: docker: unknown flag: --tag

Tags: docker, vcluster

I am setting up vcluster for development: [docs](https://github.com/loft-sh/vcluster/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#setup-vcluster-for-development)

```
devspace run dev

....
[info]   Using namespace 'vcluster'
[info]   Using kube context 'vhost'
[done] √ Created namespace: vcluster
[info]   Rebuild image  because tag is missing                      
[info]   Building image 'ghcr.io/loft-sh/loft-enterprise/dev-vcluster:kSukXFs' with engine 'buildkit'
[info]   Execute BuildKit command with: docker buildx build --tag ghcr.io/loft-sh/loft-enterprise/dev-vcluster:kSukXFs --push --file Dockerfile --target builder -
unknown flag: --tag
See 'docker --help'.

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND
...
Run 'docker COMMAND --help' for more information on a command.

To get more help with docker, check out our guides at https://docs.docker.com/go/guides/

[fatal]  error building image ghcr.io/loft-sh/loft-enterprise/dev-vcluster:kSukXFs: exit status 125
```

Is my version of docker too old?

I am using `Docker version 20.10.12`

Comment: That is quite an unexpected error, because as far as I can tell from the source code, the "--tag" flag should be there in your docker version.
Do you see the flag in the help output - `docker buildx build --help | grep -e "--tag"` ?


Also, are you sure that you are using CLI of the version that you mentioned? I for example have podman-docker package installed, which overrides the `docker` CLI, so while I could be running some docker daemon version x.y.z, the CLI would be completely different.

Comment: @matskiv I upgraded to docker `20.10.17` and now it works.

Comment: If anybody else has this error, in my case it was because`docker-buildx-plugin` was not installed.